# Solve ODE that depends on x in R?

Tags: r, ode

Consider the following ODE with boundary condition

```
y'[x] = (a - 1)*y[x]/x

y[1] = a*b
```

where a > 0, b > 0, and x > 0.

I want to solve this ODE numerically in R using the command `ode` from the R package `deSolve`.

**This is, I want to calculate the solution `y[x]` for `x>0`**

**Questions**: (i) I do not know how to include "x" in the denominator in the model equation. (ii) I also don't know how to specify the initial condition.

**Disclaimer**: I know this equation has an analytical solution, but I am trying to compare it with the numerical solution.

So far, I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
library(deSolve)

difeq <- function(x, y, parms) {

  a <- parms[1]
  b <- parms[2]
  
  # model equations
  dy <-  y*(a - 1)/***x*** # HOW TO SPECIFY x?
  
  # result  
  return( list(dy) )

}

params  <- c(a = 2, b = 1)
init      <- c(y = params[1]*params[2]) # HOW TO SPECIFY THE INITIAL CONDITION?
times  <- seq(0,5, by = 0.1)
out <- ode(init, times, difeq, params)

plot(out)
```

Comment: Looks like `x` should be one of the elements of `params`.

Comment: @RobertDodier So, do I need to include `x <- parms[3]`?

Comment: @tpetzoldt I tried, but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I take it back. I think you just want `x` as the independent variable, as the other user is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the equation, I would say that `x` is equivalent to time `t`. Package `deSolve` uses time in the denominator because this is quite common, but it is not limited to time dependent systems. It can also be something else, e.g. a spatial component, just set `x=t`, that works exactly the same.

Note also to avoid `0` in the denominator.

```r
library(deSolve)

difeq <- function(x, y, parms) {

  a <- parms[1]
  b <- parms[2]
  
  # model equations
  dy <-  y * (a - 1) / x
  
  # result  
  return(list(y=dy))
}

params <- c(a = 2, b = 1)
init   <- c(y = unname(params[1]*params[2]))
times  <- seq(1, 5, by = 0.1)
out    <- ode(init, times, difeq, params)

## just rename "time" to "x"
colnames(out)[1] <- "x"
head(out)
```

To get the initial value at `x -> 0` one may use an optimizer, run the system backwards (see separate answer) or use another solver (see [CRAN Task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/DifferentialEquations.html)).

```
   time    y
1   1.0  2.0
2   1.1  2.2
3   1.2  2.4
4   1.3  2.6
5   1.4  2.8
6   1.5  3.0
7   1.6  3.2
8   1.7  3.4
```

Comment: But why does the solution do not satisfy `y[1] = 2`?

Comment: Last question, if I also want the solution for `x<1` how can I get the correct values?

Comment: Thanks, I will leave the question open in case anyone else wants to provide the full answer. The idea is to get the solution `y[x]` for `x>0`, not just for `x>t_0`.

Comment: @SnoopDogg The answer is correct, even though the comment "start with value > 0" is misleading: the first value of the time vector must be the initial time, and here it's 1 (you write "boundary condition", but it's an initial value problem). You may pick decreasing values of time, to get the solution for any *representable* double precision number x>0. Note however, that there are only finitely many double precision numbers, so effectively you are going to compute the solution for x>=x0>0. You will also be limited by the precision of the method and the convergence criterion.

Comment: @SnoopDogg The solutions satisfies `y[1]=2`, as is shown in the first row of the output table. The column labelled `y.a` is the solution `y`. The label is not `y` because of an obscure feature of R, in `init <- c(y = params[1]*params[2])`. If you write instead `init <- c(y = params[[1]]*params[[2]])`, the label is `y` as expected.

Comment: @SnoopDogg Here is the trick: `params[1]*params[2]` and `params[[1]]*params[[2]]` both produce a vector, but the former keeps the name `a` of the first operand. Then, `c(y = ...)` concatenates the names `y` and `a`. The same happens with `c(y = c(a = 2))`. Incidentally, if you define `u <- c(x = v)` with an arbitrary `v`, then `u[["x"]]` may fail, depending on the actual content of `v`. To me it looks like a great misfeature.

Comment: Instead of `[[]]` one can also use `unname`. Comment "start with >0" was used because at  `time = 0`  a division by zero would occur.

Comment: The indexing operator is `[[`, while `[` is a subsetting operator, hence for indexing `[[` is better. Even better would be `params[["a"]] * params[["b"]]` as it's more explicit.

Comment: Thank you all for the discussion and answers. They are very useful and illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Another part of the question was, how to specify the initial condition at **x>0**. As this is a somewhat additional question to the technical part how to include x in the denominator, I will give it as separate answer.

The approach uses a backward simulation. As negative time steps are not supported in **deSolve** a workaround can be used:

- Instead of running the simulation from 1 to 0 backwards, we run it forward from -1 to 0.
- Because of a pole at x=0, we use a small value close to zero.
- In the model, we change the sign of the derivative, and as x appears also in the model, we multiply it with the sign too.
- Note: this is explicitly included here to show the general approach for didactical reasons. In the special case here, signs will of course cancel out.

In the script below, we first start integration from the known initial value at x=1. Then we do the "backward" integration to estimate the initial value close to zero. Finally we run the model with the new initial value for the whole range of x and compare the results.

```r
library(deSolve)

difeq <- function(x, y, parms, sign = 1) {
  with(as.list(parms),{
    dy <-  sign * y * (a - 1) / (sign * x)
    return(list(y=dy))
  })
}

## initial simulation starting at x = 1
params  <- c(a = 2, b = 1, sign = 1)
init    <- c(y = params[["a"]] * params[["b"]])
times   <- seq(1, 5, by = 0.1)
out1    <- ode(init, times, difeq, params)

## backwards simulation
close_to_zero <- 1e-16 # numerical precision is limited, do not decrease this more
times  <-  c(-1, -close_to_zero)
out0 <- ode(init, times, difeq, params, sign = -1)

## forward simulation starting close to zero
times  <- c(close_to_zero, seq(0.1, 10, 0.1))
init   <- c(y = out0[[nrow(out0), 2]])
cat("y[", close_to_zero,"] =", init, "\n")
out2   <- ode(init, times, difeq, params)#, hmax=0.01)

## comparison of the initial simulation with an extended time period
plot(out2, out1, lwd=c(1, 5), lty=c("solid", "dotted"), xlab="x")
```

[image: comparison of out1 and out2]